# Dingo APi error message

Tags: laravel, html-email, dingo-api

I am trying to [render](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#previewing-mailables-in-the-browser) my mailable in the browser in order to check the content. However I'm getting this message `{"message":"sha1() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given","status_code":500}`

[My code snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1695247)

I am running Dingo/Api on my page as well an I think it's somehow connected with it.

Can you please give me the suggestion why am I getting this message instead of rendering mailable?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We got this to work by assigning the mailable to a var first and then directly calling the render function on it, like so:

```
$mailable = new YourMailableName();
return $mailable->render();
```